# Prove that the tangent at $P$ intersects $C$ twice at $P$ and once at $4P$; the tangent at $5P$ intersects $C$ twice at $5P$ and once at $2P$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

This is a problem from Conics and Cubics by Bix. Please help me answer this one.

Let $C$ be a nonsingular, irreducible cubic with a flex $O$. Add points (commutative) of $C$ with respect to $O$ as base point. Let $P$ be a point on $C$ of order 6. Prove that the tangent at $P$ intersects $C$ twice (counting multiplicities) at $P$ and once at $4P$. Prove that the tangent at $5P$ intersects $C$ twice at $5P$ and once at $2P$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the group law, which says if $L$, a line intersects $C$ at 3 points $A,B,C$, then $A+B+C=O$. If $P$ is of order 6, the tangent line at $P$ meets it at least twice and if $B$ is the third point, then $2\cdot  P+B=O$ and since $6P=O$, we get $B=4P$. Identical argument for $5P$, since $2\cdot 5P+2P=O$.